# Передать данные из одного процесса в другой

Tags: c#, c++, winforms, winapi

Исходные данные: имеется приложение WinAPI C++(сервер). Приложению известен дескриптор процесса приложения Windows Form C#(клиент). Сервер создает данные и посылает их клиенту:

```
COPYDATASTRUCT cds;
cds.dwData = 1;
cds.lpData = "dddd";
cds.cbData = 4;

PostMessage(hwnd/*повторюсь, дескриптор получателя известен*/, WM_COPYDATA, NULL, (LPARAM)&cds);
```

Далее, клиенту надо их принять. Принимаю так:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct COPYDATASTRUCT
{
    public IntPtr dwData;
    public int cbData;
    public IntPtr lpData;
}

private const int WM_COPYDATA = 0x004A;

protected override void WndProc(ref Message m)
    {
        switch(m.Msg) 
        {
            case WM_COPYDATA:
                {
                    string message = "";
                    unsafe
                    {
                        COPYDATASTRUCT* cds = (COPYDATASTRUCT*)m.LParam;
                        message = Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(cds->lpData);
                    }
                    this.Log.Text += message; // Log - это richtextbox
                    break;
                }

        }
        base.WndProc(ref m);
    }
```

Однако, клиент сообщение не ловит(изменений в richtextbox) не фиксируется. 
В чем беда? Спасибо.
P.S.: посмотрел в spy - сообщение не приходит.

Comment: Гм, `"dddd"` - это ж локальные данные. Тут нужен указатель на данные в куче, не? Иначе другой процесс рискует получить мусор.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov: Вроде бы `WM_COPYDATA` должно смаршаллировать. Но вот только код на принимающей стороне мне что-то не очень нравится.

Comment: А почему `Marshal.PtrToStringAnsi(cds->lpData);`? Что у вас лежит по указателю? Посмотрите в отладчике.

Comment: @VladD собственно, получаем неуправляемую строку аски и преобразуем ее в управляемый System.String и юникод. Как же я поймаю этот шаг, если принимающая сторона не ловит сообщение WM_COPYDATA? В этом вся проблема.

Comment: @Range: А, сообщение _не приходит_?

Comment: @VladD именно, что не приходит. Я дополнил пост, в spy сообщения нет. Однако, я решился на радикальные методы: вставил сообщение в самый верх очереди(SendMessage) и оно тут же пришло и обработалось. Данные верны. Но..почему с PostMessage такая проблема?

Comment: @Range: А если SendMessage? https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110916-00/?p=9623

Comment: @VladD выше  описал:)

Comment: @Range: А по ссылке написано, почему PostMessage не прокатит

Comment: @VladD премного Вам благодарен!

Comment: @Range: Рад, что смог помочь. Почитаю сам, чтобы понять :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сообщение `WM_COPYDATA` нужно посылать через `SendMessage`, а не `PostMessage`. С `PostMessage` работать не может, и возвращаемое значение `PostMessage` должно вам сказать, что отправка не произошла.

[Из win32.hlp](http://www.qsl.net/dl4yhf/yhf_comm/yhf_comm_info.htm) (но почему-то этого нет на MSDN):

> An application must use the `SendMessage` function to send this message, not the `PostMessage` function.
>
> The data being passed must not contain pointers or other references to objects not accessible to the application receiving the data.
>
> While this message is being sent, the referenced data must not be changed by another thread of the sending process.
>
> The receiving application should consider the data read-only. The pcds parameter is valid only during the processing of the message. The receiving application should not free the memory referenced by pcds. If the receiving application must access the data after `SendMessage` returns, it must copy the data into a local buffer.

---

Почему так происходит?

Дело в том, что ваше сообщение будет смаршаллировано в другой процесс. Оконный менеджер должен будет знать, когда обработка окончена, чтобы освободить свой буфер, который он использовал для маршаллирования. Но для `PostMessage` отправка происходит асинхронно, и оконный менеджер не знает, когда сообщение будет обработано, и когда можно подчищать память.

Дополнительное чтение по теме: [Why can’t I PostMessage the WM_COPYDATA message, but I can SendMessageTimeout it with a tiny timeout?](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20110916-00/?p=9623)